# How can one run tomcat as root?

Tags: tomcat, centos5

I'm not an admin by choice and quite new to admin and admin policies. Now I know I need to bind tomcat to root somehow; at the moment I route all port 80 traffic to tomcat standard with iptables, but it seems the app cannot be accessed from some rented office sites, reason I was given was that they only allow outgoing comms on the standard ports from these sites and firewall admin refuses to budge. 
I have googled a fair few ways to resolve my question but I'm more confused than before I started searching as a lot of the pages are quite old. I am using a rented CentOS virtual server (5.4) with tomcat5.5 with java 1.6 (openjdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just simply used the proxyPort and proxyName attribute of the tomcat connector and added forwarding rules to iptables. Works like a dream.

Comment: Perfect!  (Running Tomcat as root is Just Wrong.)

Answer (score 4):

Leave tomcat running as a non-privileged user, enable a JK connector, run apache on port 80 and use mod_jk to have it talk to tomcat.

This guy below wrote instructions for tomcat 6 but the same functionality is also available for tomcat 5.5.  In fact, everything you need is available as a CentOS package, including mod_jk for apache.

http://adcasein.blogspot.com/2010/06/install-modjk-on-centos-55.html

Good luck.

Comment: Was told mod_jk was the old mod and to use mod_ajp instead. In any case I had it setup but I have a problem with plesk

Comment: @Dark Star1: that could be right - I'm not sure which one ships with CentOS 5 but they serve the same purpose.  I can't help with plesk, sorry.